# Fetching Netbeans Lookup multiple instances of a service

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-platform

The topic is simply about: **Lookups for loading services in a NetBeans RCP application**

I have a service provider named `WordFilter` and I have a GUI that contains **2 buttons** the first for uppercasing the content of the text area and the second for lowercasing it (when clicked).
For each button, I have attached a service that implements my service provider; the first is `UpperCaseFilter` and the second is `LowerCaseFilter`.

The action code of one button is :

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String enteredText = text.getText();
        Collection<? extends WordFilter> allFilters = Lookup.getDefault().lookupAll(WordFilter.class);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (WordFilter textFilter : allFilters) {
                String processedText = textFilter.process(enteredText);
                sb.append(processedText).append("\n");
        }
        text.setText(sb.toString());
    }
```

What happens is: when I click the `Button2` (for lowercasing), the two actions run simultanously, I want to check which of the instances to run because `allFilters` give me the two instances

Comment: Since you have buttons to convert string to upper/lower case, why not you just get the text from text area and call toLowerCase() and toUpperCase() ?

Comment: I am working on a Netbeans Platform Application, which should be modular

Answer (score 0):

Since you have implement two services `UpperCaseFilter` and `LowerCaseFilter` you can use those filters separately in lookup process.

*EX: Action method for convert to upper case*

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                         
    String enteredText = text.getText();
    UpperCaseFilter uFilter = (UpperCaseFilter)Lookup.getDefault().lookup(UpperCaseFilter.class)

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String processedText = uFilter.process(enteredText);
    sb.append(processedText).append("\n");

    text.setText(sb.toString());
}
```